# Merge multiple declarative bases in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to merge a _BoundDeclarativeMeta instance with another?

For example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base1 = declarative_base()
Base2 = declarative_base()

# Something like this?
CombinedBase = Base1.merge(Base2)
```

In reality I would be subclassing orm models from each of them before merging.  The problem is that I have an independent package that needs certain tables to work.  Yet it is going to be used by another independent package.

Answer (score 10):

For my use case this worked:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

combined_meta_data = MetaData()

for declarative_base in [Base1, Base2]:
    for (table_name, table) in declarative_base.metadata.tables.items():
        combined_meta_data._add_table(table_name, table.schema, table)
```

Or, even better, automatically merge all declarative bases:

```
import gc
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

combined_meta_data = MetaData()

for declarative_base in ([obj for obj in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(obj, DeclarativeMeta)]):
    for (table_name, table) in declarative_base.metadata.tables.items():
        combined_meta_data._add_table(table_name, table.schema, table)
```

That meta data can then be used for example to create a diff to the current database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from alembic.migration import MigrationContext
from alembic.autogenerate import compare_metadata
import pprint

engine = create_engine(...)
migration_context = MigrationContext.configure(engine.connect())

diff = compare_metadata(migration_context, combined_meta_data)
pprint.pprint(diff)
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this that uses only the stable SQ API, not `_add_table`?

Answer (score 8):

[`sqlalchemy.Table.to_metadata`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.to_metadata) appears to be a non-internal API that can copy a Table from one metadata object to another.

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    
def merge_metadata(*original_metadata) -> MetaData:
    merged = MetaData()

    for original_metadatum in original_metadata:
        for table in original_metadatum.tables.values():
            table.to_metadata(merged)
    
    return merged

Base1 = declarative_base()
Base2 = declarative_base()
print(merge_metadata(Base1.metadata, Base2.metadata).tables)
```

Comment: This works and seems to be the most recent way to do it in 2021

Comment: This works great when needing to convert `DeclarativeBase`-inherited models that use plain `SQLAlchemy` into `Flask-SQLAlchemy` `db.Model`-inherited models purely for testing purposes. In my case, I needed to convert tables that utilize `sqlalchemy-bigquery`+a separate declarative base into `Flask-SQLAlchemy` `db.Models` in order to have them in a temporary SQLite database for straightforward tests that don't rely on outside connections.