# SQLAlchemy - Merge/extend existing metadata?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metadata

Background:

- I have a library that describes a database using SQLAlchemy. They have their own declarative_base() and MetaData.
- In another project, I have another set of declarative classes that describe some additional tables. They also have their own Base and MetaData.
- Some of these tables have foreign keys that reference tables from the first library.
- SQLAlchemy fails to setup foreign keys or relationships, because the referenced tables and the referencing tables are not in the same MetaData (it doesn't "see" the referenced tables)

Questions:

- Is there a way to "merge" tables from the first library into the MetaData of the second library?

  - Reflecting the other database through the second library's MetaData almost works, but SQLAlchemy then won't recognize that they have been mapped declaratively.
- Alternatively, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954815/merge-multiple-declarative-bases-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of [Merge multiple declarative bases in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954815/merge-multiple-declarative-bases-in-sqlalchemy)